# InfoBox doesn't communicate with the Server in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm making a shiny dashboard. But it seems my dashboard doesn't communicate with the server when infoBoxOutput is used. It doesn't even appear. Can someone kindly look into the following code and let me know the issue here.

If I just simply use Infobox, it prints info_box1 but doesn't communicate with the server. When infoBoxOutput is used even it doesn't show up in the dashboard body.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

source("D:/Upwork/MAL/3rd-Data Visualization/RCodes/MalServer.R")

shinyUI <-
  dashboardPage( title="Demo App",
    
    dashboardHeader(title="Covid-19 Death Analysis",dropdownMenuOutput("msgOutput")
                    # dropdownMenu(type="message",
                    #              messageItem(from="Finance Update", message = "We are on threshold"),
                    #              messageItem(from = "Sales Update", message = "Sales are at 55%", icon=icon("bar-chart") , time="22:00"),
                    #              messageItem(from="Sales Update",message = "Sales meeting at 6 PM on Monday", icon=icon("handshake-o"),time="03-22-2021")
                    #              )
                    
                    ),
    
    dashboardSidebar( width =320,useShinyjs(),
  
      sidebarMenu(
        width = 2,
        
        dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                       label = 'Filter crimes by date',
                       start = as.Date('2019-01-01') , end = as.Date('2021-06-01')),
        
        selectInput("var", label = "1. Select the quantitative Variable", 
                    choices = c("place_of_death"=3,"Month Name"=11, "cause_of_death"=8), selected = 8), 
        
        radioButtons( "dist", "Enable or disable Grouping:",
                      c("Enable" = "enable",
                        "Disable" = "disable" ), inline=T),
        
        selectInput("var2", label = "1. Select the quantitative Variable", 
                    choices = c("cause_of_death"=8, "year"=7), selected = 7),
        
        
        radioButtons( "CauseOfDeathRad", "Enable or disable Grouping:",
                      c("Covid" = "covid",
                        "Non-Covid" = "nonCovid" ,
                        "Both" = "both"), inline=T),
        
        radioButtons( "DeathonYearRad", "Enable or disable Grouping:",
                      c(
                        "2020" = "2020" ,
                        "2021" = "2021",
                        "All" = "All"), inline=T)
      
      
    )),
    
    dashboardBody(
      
      useShinyjs(),
      #Second Row:
      
        infoBoxOutput('info_box1'),
        infoBox('Loading %', '0.97%', icon = icon('percent')),
        infoBox('Revenue', 'R$ 60.000,00', icon = icon('dollar-sign')),
      
        
      tabsetPanel(
        #tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("myhist")) ,
        
        tabPanel("Plot2", plotOutput("myhist2")) 
      )
      
      

    )
    )
 

shinyServer <- function(input, output ) {
  
  
  output$info_box1 <- renderInfoBox({
    infoBox("Amount in Total here", sum(mydf$Amount))
  })

}
```

shinyApp(shinyUI,shinyServer)

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me. I can see the `info_box1` output on the UI. Since I don't have `mydf`, I replaced it with a constant (100).

Comment: Works fine for me too!

Comment: Thank you guys. I put the server function in a separate file. Seems it had been not properly imported. Now works fine for me too